# Wordpress - How to display featured image from specific category as background?

Tags: php, wordpress

Firstly, PHP isn't my strong point, but here we go.

I have a function in my functions.php that grabs the featured image and sets it as the background. This function is then called in the header.php

```
function set_post_background() {
  if(query_posts(array ('category_name' => 'results')));
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        global $post;
        $bgimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "Full");
        if (!empty($bgimage)) {
            return '<style type="text/css">body {background:#fff url('.$bgimage[0].') no-repeat top center;}</style>';
        }
endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_query();
}
```

Last night, I attempted to modify the function, and wrap it in a `query_posts()` I managed to kind of get it working. It will now only fetch the featured image of a post and set it as the background if it is in the category called "results".

But something in this code is wrong, as now none of my page content appears. Disable the function, content comes back.

What have I done wrong?

[edit] I think it's the way in which I am querying the category name. because page.php similar queries which get `the_content()`I think the function is overriding that query, and therefor not displaying the pages content.

Comment: your project is on live where I can see what is happening?

Comment: It's local only atm. with the function active, it seems that this code (post.php)

`<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
     <?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>
      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
     <?php } else { ?> 
      <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
     <?php } ?>    
      <?php the_content(); ?>
      <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyten' ), 'after' => '' ) ); ?>
      <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyten' ), '', '' ); ?>
    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>`
doesn't load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're using [`query_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) which will alter the results of the default main query. It means the default contents of the page will be altered by contents from `results` category. Try this:

```
function set_post_background() {
    $query = new \WP_Query(['category_name' => 'results']);
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        $bgimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($query->post->ID), 'full');
        if (!empty($bgimage)) {
            return '<style type="text/css">body{background:#fff url('.$bgimage[0].') no-repeat top center}</style>';
        }
        endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

Under any circumstances, **do not use `query_posts()` function** to query posts. From reference:

> **Note**: This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).

Comment: Hi, it's weird. As you posted this, I edited mine to say I think its the query that's causing it.

syntax error though
`$query = new \WP_Query(['category_name' => 'results']);`

Comment: @peterbeard The function works fine. What PHP version you're using? Change `['category_name' => 'results']` to `array('category_name' => 'results')` then see what happens.

Comment: we're getting somewhere. That change kinda worked. It's now getting the featured image of the post in category "results", which is good. But it's now seems to only be getting it for the first post in that category, and not the latest one? So example, i have "post 1" and "post 2". Even with "post 2" set to the category "results" - it displays the featured image of "post 1"

Comment: @peterbeard Right after the first `$bgimage` was found inside the loop, we return the CSS then the loop will stop. So if both `post 1` and `post 2` have `featured image`, the `featured image` of `post 1` will be displayed. That's normal. To get the last `featured image` you can change the order of the queried posts by using [`'order' => 'ASC'`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

Comment: of course! Well that works perfectly now, and you've saved me a lot of headache! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Please replace following code for your code and it should work fine.

```
function set_post_background() {
$cat_ids=array();
$img='';
$cat_ids=wp_get_post_categories();

foreach($cat_ids as $cat_id){
    $img=wpds_tax_pic_url($cat_id);
}
if (!empty($img)) {
  return '<style type="text/css">body {background:#fff url('.$img.') no-repeat top center;}</style>';
}}
```

And also you can set default image on "else" statement

Try it!...

Comment: Thanks for response. where in this code do I define the category name?

Comment: You don't need to specify category name. "wp_get_post_categories" get current post object associated category ids. So Replace your fuction there